# pyinstaller exe multiple files result in error of can't find directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Ppl

I compiled a simple code it works on my machine but when i try to run the exe from another machine I get an error that it can't find the script which is called from main

so I have to python files
main.
Script

I am calling Script from main using this function

```
def execfile(filepath, globals=None, locals=None):
    if globals is None:
        globals = {}
    globals.update({
        "__file__": filepath,
        "__name__": "__main__",
    })
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        exec(compile(file.read(), filepath, 'exec'), globals, locals)
```

the way I am calling is this, very simple minded approach

```
 execfile("Script.py",globals=None,locals=None)
```

when i try to run it from another machine i get the error
no such file or directory Script.py

I want to understand since the scripts are called from one another why is pyinstaller exe is not having both files, i have tried the add-data but i dont seem to understand what does it do exactly and it didn't work in my case to have the exe running on other machines

python 3.9.10
windows 11

Comment: it seems like it tries to find the second file using its path in the development file, i am curious why has it not been included in the pyinstaller exe file